# Ploting degree distribution for multiple graphs

Tags: r, igraph

I have an object that contains multiple graphs named: *graphs*

I want to plot the degree distributions for these graphs in one plot.
I tried the following code but I keep getting the following error: " 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'"

Here is the code:

```
library(igraph)
getDD  <- function(graph, cumulative = FALSE, ...) {
  if (!is.igraph(graph)) {
    stop("Not a graph object")
  }
  cs <- degree(graph, ...)
  hi <- hist(cs, -1:max(cs), plot = FALSE)$density
  if (!cumulative) {
    res <- hi
  } else {
    res <- rev(cumsum(rev(hi)))
  }
  res
}

generateGraph <- function(x){
return (barabasi.game(100))  
}

# generate 5 graphs
graphs = lapply(1:5, generateGraph)
dDistributions = lapply(graphs, getDD)

plot(dDistributions,  xlab="degree", ylab="cumulative frequency", main="Degree distribution", type="o")
```

Comment: `plot()` cannot handle lists, go over the list one by one, after setting up the plot properly. Or transform your list to a matrix and use `matplot()`. I'll give an example solution as soon as you make your code reproducible. (I.e. include some test data and the `getDD` function.

Answer (score 1):

`plot()` cannot handle lists, go over the list one by one, after setting up the plot properly. I.e. something like this:

```
xlim <- c(0, max(sapply(dDistributions, length)-1))
ylim <- c(0, max(unlist(dDistributions)))

plot(NA, type="n", xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xlab="degree", ylab="relative frequency")
sapply(dDistributions, function(x) lines(1:length(x)-1, x, type="l"))
```